# rails multi-levels of "through", database schema layering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, associations

my data is currently structured in the following way.

STATE (ie California) "has_many" SCHOOLS, 
 SCHOOL "has_many" GRADES (ie 8th grade or 9th grade), 
 GRADE "has_many" CLASSES (ie art, history, chemistry), 
 CLASSES "has_many" STUDENTS.

My goal is to get low-level detail from a high-level view, otherwise, I would like to get all students (lowest denominator within the data structure) within the STATE (highest level component within the structure). What's the easiest and most efficient way to structure this so I can have a command to get all students within a state, ie "State.find(name: "California").students".

I tried a two level "through" association but it seems to be limited.

Comment: Do you need to keep a record of all the schools a user has attended (if a student changes schools) or do you only need the current school? This really effects the relations modeling since in the first case you would need to setup has and belongs to many relations between Users -> Schools  and User -> District

Comment: yea there would be a track record of all the different schools a student attended each year. however, in general, is it advisable to have this many level deep data structure? or is it better to flatten it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential basic data design would be something like the following:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schools
  has_many :students, through: :schools
end

# Links students to schools
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :grade
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :students, through: :enrollments
  has_many :grades
  has_many :subjects, through: :grades
  belongs_to :state
end

# Denotes a educational step as in 1st grade
class Grade
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :subjects
end

# We can't use Class since it clashes with the Class object. 
class Subject
  belongs_to :grade  
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :schools, through: :enrollments
end
```

`State.find(1).students` would join through `School` and `Enrollment`.

Flattening the structure would require a `states_students` join table which is pretty unsexy due to data duplication. The duplication means more slow insert and update queries when creating / updating students. The same applies to subjects and grades.

This does not address differentiating between current and former students which could be solved by adding an end date or a enum denoting the status to `Enrollment`.

Enougher issue is dealing with data that might be shared by all Grades or Classes. Like for example goals that would be setup on a state level and not on a school level. Another case is a subject which might stretch though several grades.

Comment: I would also try to find some synonym for Grade (as in 1st grade) to avoid confusion with class grading (as in A+) but I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: I guess you could use the UK english term `marks` for class grading.

Comment: I hope this answers your question. Its hard to generically say that flat or nested data stuctures are good/bad. Its always a trade off between data duplication and complexity (those join queries can get totally nuts).